# xcode 4.6.3: Master-Detail Application shows blank Navigation in Simulator

Tags: ios, ipad, master-detail

SO,
I am new to iOS programming (and Macs for that matter!) and having trouble getting my feet wet with the Master-Detail Application template in Xcode (specifically for an iPad).

I created a new project using standard settings, then went to the auto-generated "Mobile Master View Controller" entry on the storyboard (I believe it's called a "scene") and added a a bunch of static table cells and a couple of groupings. Looks great in the Storyboard!

When I run it in the Simulator, the navigation is completely blank. I've tried googling and researching, but I don't know if I'm using the correct terminology or keywords as I can't find an answer to something that seems very simple... I've seen some tutorials that mention right-clicking and dragging things in the Storyboard to create IBOutlets and other connections, but I don't know if that's needed here or not.

I have no code to present yet as this is all done in the Storyboard so far. Is any code needed to make this work or am I missing a setting perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial should help to you: http://www.raywenderlich.com/29469/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-in-ios-6-uisplitview-tutorial